# copy row from one datatable to another datatable using java script

Tags: javascript, datatables

```
$('#billListTable tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
  var table = $('#billListTable').DataTable();
  var data = table.row( this ).data();
  var table1=$('#billListTable1').DataTable();
  $("#billListTable1").DataTable().rows.add(data.toArray()).draw();
});
```

It is showing the data when we are printing in `console` but not adding the `row`.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: I guess, you may simply do `table1.row.add(data).draw()`

Answer (score 2):

Change `rows.add()` to `row.add()`

It appears you are only adding a single row. You've used the wrong API method.

Comment: Concurred! I would think this is the culprit, too.